# Specify cursor position and mode when opening file in vim

Tags: bash, vim, vimrc, cursor

I want cursor to be in the last character of first line, in INSERT mode when I open a file in vim.

It should work in all cases::

1. Open file from CLI, like, `$ vim fileName`
2. Open file from inside vim, like `:e fileName`
3. Open file from inside vim in new window, like `:split fileName`

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufReadPost *  startinsert!
```

From :h usr_40.3

> The general form of the :autocmd command is as follows: >

```
:autocmd [group] {events} {file_pattern} [nested] {command}
```

From - http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:startinsert

> :star[tinsert][!]
>   Start Insert mode just after executing this command.
>               Works like typing "i" in Normal mode.  When the ! is
>               included it works like "A", append to the line.
>               Otherwise insertion starts at the cursor position.